# Работа с динамически созданными данными

Tags: jquery

```
$('#query__search__audio__post').keyup(function(){
   ....
});
```

Работает только если объект с ид **query__search__audio__post** находится на странице, но если он подгружен через Ajax, то не работает.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, уже ответы на эти вопросы, их миллионы на стаковерфлоу. Зачем плодить ещё 300 таких же?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("keyup", '#query__search__audio__post', function(){
   ....
});
```